# Closing a minimized app does not allow to save "actual" size to registry

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF project that saves its window dimensions (Left, Top, Width, Height) to the registry when the OnClosing event is triggered. There is a bug that occurs when the window is closed when minimized. Instead of writing the pre-minimized window dimensions, it will write a different set of dimensions (it seems by visual inspection to be the MinWidth, MinHeight). I still would like to be able to close my app and have my actual dimensions written to the registry.

I tried using the StateChanged event. This would not work because the state is already minimized by the time the event triggers.

What other event could I use to be able to save my actual size? I believe there is not a "StateChanging" event that I could use to save my dimensions to the registry before the minimization happens.

Comment: Just save the current size in a private field?

Comment: I did not think that would be a good idea since I would have to add a lot of extra code to deal with updating the private fields. And I would rather not have a bunch of new variables floating around for that purpose exclusively.

Comment: Leaving the previous dimension unchanged when the state is Minimized is not an option?

Comment: Can you do something with the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx)?

Comment: @Steve: The dimensions change automatically. The Window class has fields Left, Top, Width, Height that control the position of the window. The process of changing the window state to minimized changes these dimensions under the hood for reasons I do not fully understand.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766709/minimized-window-position-in-wpf

Comment: I was coming back here to this page after looking at the property RestoreBounds and I see that @MichaelGunter has already pointed you to the right direction.

Comment: I tried this with great success:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766709/minimized-window-position-in-wpf

RestoreBounds seems to capture the older bounds and stores them for you. Great little thing to know!

Comment: Just use the SizeChanged event to record the new size.  It doesn't fire when the window is getting minimized.

Comment: @HansPassant And the nice thing about Hans' answer is that it'll work if the app crashes ungracefully too...